# How to use hrtimer if the processing time of the callback function is dynamic?

Tags: c, timer, linux-kernel, interrupt, kernel-module

I am writing a kernel module in which I need to trigger a function on a periodic basis. The function will access a queue and process its elements. The number of elements in the queue is dynamic and so the processing time.

In the following code, I have added 1ms sleep to represent the processing time. I am getting this error : `[116588.117966] BUG: scheduling while atomic: systemd-journal/408/0x00010000`. If my understanding is correct, this happens since I try to sleep 1ms when the expiry time of the hr_timer is just 1us. I can increase this expiry time but the processing time of the queue can be sometimes more than seconds, sometimes in hours even. Please help me to achieve this.

```
unsigned long timer_interval_ns = 1e3;
static struct hrtimer hr_timer;

enum hrtimer_restart timer_callback( struct hrtimer *timer_for_restart )
{
    uint64_t rawtime;
    struct timespec curtime;
    ktime_t currtime , interval;

    / * My Operations would take ~ 1ms, so adding 1ms for simplicity* /
    msleep(1);

    currtime = ktime_get();
    interval = ktime_set(0,timer_interval_ns);

    hrtimer_forward(timer_for_restart, currtime, interval);

    return HRTIMER_RESTART;
}

static int __init timer_init(void) {
    ktime_t ktime = ktime_set( 0, timer_interval_ns );
    hrtimer_init( &hr_timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL );
    hr_timer.function = &timer_callback;
    hrtimer_start( &hr_timer, ktime, HRTIMER_MODE_REL );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Scheduling while atomic" indicates that you've tried to sleep somewhere that you shouldn't - like within a spinlock-protected critical section or an **interrupt handler**.

Comment: @LPs, then do you have any idea why the simple code above throws such error

Comment: My guess is that msleep can't be used inside a timer callback. If you want to emulate a long execution in the context of timer callback (that it's somewhat similar to an interrupt context), you should use an active loop long enough.

Comment: You cannot do msleep because of it call schedule (that works on tasks) while interrupt must be atomic. In your case, that is a test case only, you should use a short-loop to perform your delay.

Comment: Include `linux/delay.h` and then you can use `mdelay()` instead of `msleep()` to get rid of scheduler messing with atomic context.

Comment: Also note that even if you make your `My Opeation` work, the resetting of the timer afterwards will most likely not work as you expect it to. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35940137/3306678

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> BUG: scheduling while atomic

This message means that while you are in an *atomic context* you tried to schedule some other task.

To make it easy (so, not perfect and orthodox explanation): if a function is running in an atomic context, this function cannot *stop* its execution and call the scheduler (a.k.a. sleeping).

When you call `msleep(1)` you are actually asking the kernel to schedule some other task because for 1 millisecond you do not have anything to do and you ask the kernel to use this time to do something useful. But this is not allowed in an *atomic context*. Functions running in an atomic context **must** finish their execution without any interruption.

Another example of function that will sleep and you may have the temptation to use is `kmalloc`. If you need it in an atomic context then use the `GFP_ATOMIC` flag in order to have an atomic allocation that does not sleep (schedule).

Another example of *atomic context* is the interrupt handler function.

Another problem that you may have with `msleep(1)` is that is not guaranteed that it will sleep 1 millisecond. It it too short to be guaranteed. Indeed, it is suggested to use a sleeping time greater or equal than 20 milliseconds. If you need a shorter sleeping time, then use delay functions.

Read The following links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability

https://lwn.net/Articles/274695/

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt